# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager calls success block against dead server

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I couldn't find a question answering this exact question. So here goes..

Caveat: I'm an iOS and Objective-C newbie. I'm using AFNetworking 2.0 in an iOS 7.0 app to perform an async network request. The code block is as follows:

```
- (void)requestLoad {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"http://localhost:8000/api"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"The AFHTTP op returned successfully");
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"The AFHTTP op failed");
     }];
}
```

While performing the first request (first call of this method), I get a successful return log, however then I take the server down and perform the same request over the iOS simulator: I still keep getting a successful return.

I'm guessing there's some type of URL cache in the library or iOS itself, but I've not been able to shut it down. Or is it something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set a cache up with NSURLCache?

Comment: powerj1984 - no I never set up a cache, I also tried using AFHTTPRequestOperation with NSURLRequest which I explicitly set cache to 0, to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to explicitly override the NSURLRequest cache behavior with `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`, as the default in `requestWithURL:` will by default set the `cachePolicy` to `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`. So if your server specifies a cache max age of 300, even if you tear down the server between requests, NSURLRequest will stick with the original 300 seconds cache.

The override is as follows:

```
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8000/api"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                      timeoutInterval:1.0];
```

I must also say "my bad", I remember reading previously that turning the cache off in `NSURLRequest` is by setting cachePolicy to 0, which is already the equivalent of `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` (See: [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL%3acachePolicy%3atimeoutInterval%3a)

The solution is to set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) and rebuilding it?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks a lot for the answer. Yes I have now, but this method is called multiple times during one run, actually with every invocation of viewDidAppear. I tear the server down during the run, and hit the home button, bring the app back up and see that the operation is returning successfully where it shouldn't.